# 'TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined Parse.com

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have written a background job which pushes notifications to an android user if he hasn't played for several hours. Although the scheduled job works fine and sends pushes as I intend to, job status states as "failed" Script Error:'TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined.

Any help on this would be great.

Here's my cloud code for the background job:

```
var _ = require('underscore.js'); // Javascript library for _.each()
var moment = require('moment'); // Moments library to Convert UpdatedAt to Date

Parse.Cloud.job("PushNotificationWithTime", function(request, status) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var hoursPassed = request.params.hourspassed;
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var getCurrentTime = currentDate.getTime();
    var currentDateInHours = Math.round(getCurrentTime / (1000 * 60 * 60));

    var query2 = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query2.exists('currQuestion');

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.exists('currQuestion');
    query.find({
        success : function(results) {    
            _.each(results, function(result) {
                var updatedAt = moment(result.updatedAt).toDate();          
                var userObjId = result.id;
                var getUpdatedTime = updatedAt.getTime();
                var updatedAtInHours = Math.round(getUpdatedTime/ (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var differenceInHours = currentDateInHours - updatedAtInHours;

                if (differenceInHours >= hoursPassed) {

                    query2.equalTo('objectId', userObjId);   
                    var answer = result.get('currQuestion');

                    query2.equalTo('currQuestion', result.get('currQuestion'));
                    Parse.Push.send({
                        where : query2,
                        data : {
                            alert : "Answer :" + answer
                        }
                    }, {
                        success : function() {
                            status.success("Pushed!!");    
                        },
                        error : function(error) {
                            status.error("Push.send() Error :" + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).then(function() {
                status.success("underscore.each success");
              }, function(error) {
                  status.error("underscore.each Error:" + error);
              });
        },

        error : function(error) {
            status.error("Query Error :" + error);
        }
    });

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, could you just quote the line it errors out? You know, going through a page of someone's code in search of a matching line is rather tedious.